# Do something i.e insert into another table when mysql table becomes empty

Tags: mysql

I am processing some bulk sms that are stored in the `messageout` table and once a message is sent,its deleted from the table so there is a time the `messageout` table is totally empty.

Is there a mechanism in mysql that can be used to notify when the table falls empty i.e triggers or something similar?.

Thanks.

Comment: And how you wish to be notified?

Comment: By inserting a record into another table with the flag finished alongside a timestamp.

Comment: Yes, there are triggers. Next question...

Comment: I have not heard on a trigger that runs when the table becomes empty or is there?

Comment: Of course not, but you can check if the table is empty. Use `exists()` rather than `count()`....